# I selected a column in datagridview as an array, how can i display the selected array values?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I selected a column in datagridview and put it in array, but how can i display those values on listbox or anything that can be use to just display it since i dont have any idea if i really selected those values.

This is my code, i dont know if it works, if i clicked the button nothing happens, no error or something either.

```
    Button_Click
    List<int> strval = new List<int>();
              foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
              {
              strval.Add(int.Parse(row.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString()));
              }
              int[] array = strval.ToArray();
```

Comment: Did the list or array get filled??       Do you know how to test this with the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), your very best friend in the world of coding.?

Comment: How to do that? sorry i'm a beginner in coding. Thankyou

Comment: Do follow the link above! Doing a debugger 101 is the very 1st thing to learn for beginners!!

Comment: oooh. Thankyou very much!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things that you can write things to it, like textboxs:
create a textbox then name it textbox1:

```
    Button_Click
    List<int> strval = new List<int>();
              foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
              {
              strval.Add(int.Parse(row.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString()));
              }
              int[] array = strval.ToArray();

foreach(int i in strval)
{
textbox1.text = i.toString() + "\n";
}
```

Anyway, if you just want to check if you have obtain those value or not, you can put a breake point there and run your program, check the variable when your program stop at that break point.